# Topology: A subset $F$ of $X$ is "closed" if $F' \in T$

Tags: general-topology

It seems like I'm having a very hard time of understanding even the basics of topology. Might be that my problem is poorly worded, but if you understand it then I would greatly appreciate an explanation as simple as possible. Totally blank here.

Assume that $T$ is a topology on $X$. A subset $F$ of $X$ is closed if $F'\in T$ ($F'=X\setminus F$)and let $\mathcal{F}$ be the "family" of all closed sets. Show that

1. $\emptyset, X\in \mathcal{F}$.
2. If $G\subseteq \mathcal{F}$, then $\bigcap_{F\in G} F\in \mathcal{F}$
3. If $F_1, F_2,...,F_n$ is a finite number of sets in $\mathcal{F}$, then $F_1 \cup F_2 \cup. . . \cup F_n\in \mathcal{F}$.

Now. I believe that I am supposed to show that the 3 properties of set topology and the statements above correlate, but I really don't know how to show this. Again, I can not stress how clueless I am on this, so the explain like im 5 solution to the procedure and theory is appreciated if possible.

Comment: The basic thing to know are de Morgan's laws: $X \setminus (\cup_i F_i) = \cap_i (X \setminus F_i)$ and the same with intersection and union interchanged. Then they reduce to the corresponging axioms for a topology (i.e. the open sets) as you surmised.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll do the first two parts to get you started. The third part should be pretty easy after that.

I will continue to use your notation $A'$ for the complement of $A$, although this notation is somewhat nonstandard.

Also, I fixed your typesetting so $\mathcal{F}$ (note the fancy font) now refers to the family of all closed subsets of $X$, as opposed to $F$ to refer to a single closed set.

**Part 1**

Note that $\emptyset$ and $X$ are open. This is true for any topology, by definition. Since these sets are open, their complements are closed, again by definition. But $\emptyset' = X$ and $X' = \emptyset$. Therefore, $\emptyset$ and $X$ are closed, so they are in $\mathcal{F}$.

**Part 2**

Suppose $\mathcal{G} \subseteq \mathcal{F}$. This means that $\mathcal{G}$ is a collection of elements of $\mathcal{F}$. Each element of $\mathcal{F}$ is a closed subset of $X$. Therefore, $\mathcal{G}$ is a collection of closed subsets of $X$, and the notation $\bigcup_{F \in \mathcal{G}}F$ simply means the union of this collection.

More typical notation for this situation would be to say that we have a collection of closed sets $F_{\alpha} \subseteq X$, where $\alpha$ ranges over some index set, which we might call $I$. In this notation, $\bigcup_{f \in \mathcal{G}}F$ would instead be written as $\bigcup_{\alpha \in I}F_{\alpha}$. I introduce this notation because it is easier to work with, as it allows us to refer to individual sets $F_{\alpha}$.

So, each set $F_{\alpha}$ in our collection is closed, and therefore by definition each complement $F_{\alpha}'$ is open. Since any union of open sets is open, this means that $\bigcup_{\alpha \in I}F_{\alpha}'$ is open. But then by definition, the complement of this set, which is $\left(\bigcup_{\alpha \in I}F_{\alpha}'\right) = \bigcap_{\alpha \in I}F_{\alpha}$, is closed, and is therefore in $\mathcal{F}$. Since this is precisely what we needed to show, the proof for Part 2 is complete.

You should be able to do Part 3 quite analogously to Part 2.